# WPF Range Slider With Readonly Limits

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I need to allow the user of my program to select two values using a slider. As in the image below, the user would grab the blue section and slide it to the left or right. Let's pretend that the `18 comes from a binding to LowerBound` and that `52 comes from a binding to UpperBound`. The distance between these will always `remain 52 - 18 = 34, unless changed` elsewhere by the user. Otherwise, if the slider is moved to the right, the two bound values will `never be more than or less than 34 units` from each other.
How can I do this in WPF when I only have one thumb on the slider? I need something like two thumbs with the area in between them able to be selected and moved.

I suppose this is like a slider with a single thumb that is the width of the distance between the two bound values. How can I do this?

[image: range slider]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used MathApps's RangeSlider control for this. [From Here.](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)
It has MinRange and other useful (eg: MoveWholeRange) properties.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. That seems to be what I need. Is there any way to disable the thumbs on the control so only the range can be moved?

Comment: I don't want to copy the whole ControlTemplate here, because it is quite a long code. You can edit the default ControlTemplate by selecting 'Convert to local value' or 'Convert to New resource' on the Template field in the Properties window.